Count number of parallel events
I have a (long) list of events with their begin and end timestamps (or more accurately: their begin timestamps and their durations).
I need to find out, how many parallel events there have been, i. e. how many meeting rooms are needed or how many concurrent  meeting room software licenses.
For example:
Scenario 1:
Meeting A: From Jan 1, 9:00 am to 11:00 am
Meeting B: From Jan 1, 12:00 pm to 1:00 pm
Meeting C: From Jan 1, 1:30 pm to 2:00 pm

There's only one meeting at a time.
Scenario 2:
Meeting A: From Jan 2, 9:00 am to 3:00 pm
Meeting B: From Jan 2, 8:00 am to 12:00 pm
Meeting C: From Jan 2, 1:00 pm to 2:30 pm
Meeting D: From Jan 2, 9:30 pm to 10:00 pm
Meeting E: From Jan 3, 11:00 am to 12:00 am

There are three parallel meetings at the maximum. For my use case, I do not need the time intervals when there are three meetings, I just need the maximum count.
The records I have have several thousand entries... (CSV files)
I did not yet find a way to calculate that using an easy formula in Excel, but maybe there is one that can do that?
Or how else can this be done?
(To be honest, I am not even sure if this is a question for superuser.com or rather for stackoverflow.com...)

Here's suggestion to do it in Excel (for Microsoft 365). Please let me know if the performance is slow due the large amount of data - if so, will try with Power Query.

last: automatically get the last cell with data (please change D:D to match your range)
assuming duration is given in hours, get end times for events in end_calc = start +  duration
to get overlapping event count, for each event, comparing with others

get overlapping duration with MIN(end times) - MAX(start times)
count if overlapping duration > 0



=LET(
    last, XLOOKUP(TRUE, C:C <> "", C:C, , , -1),
    d, B2:last,
    end_calc, INDEX(d, , 1) + TIME(0, 60 * INDEX(d, , 2), 0),
    start, LAMBDA(i, INDEX(d, i, 1)),
    end, LAMBDA(i, INDEX(end_calc, i, 1)),
    idx, SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),
    overlap_dur, LAMBDA(i, j,
        MAX(MIN(end(i), end(j)) - MAX(start(i), start(j)))
    ),
    overlap_count, LAMBDA(i,
        SUM(--MAP(idx, LAMBDA(j, overlap_dur(i, j) > 0)))
    ),
    MAX(MAP(idx, overlap_count))
)


